# IDBTransaction: onabort vs onerror

Tags: javascript, error-handling, transactions, indexeddb

When we want to handle IndexedDB errors on the transaction level, we have two options: `onabort` and `onerror` handlers.

What is the difference between them?

MDN isn't very helpful; [it only says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction/onerror):

> Consider using `IDBTransaction.onabort` instead to handle non-
>   successful completion of the transaction.

Does this mean that `onerror` handler would handle only a subset of errors which would be handled by the `onabort` handler?

Answer (score 3):

An `error` event is fired at a failed request (`IDBRequest` instance); it bubbles up from the request to the request's transaction (`IDBTransaction`) to the transaction's connection (`IDBDatabase`). At any point it can be logged and the default behavior (aborting the transaction) can be prevented if desired by calling `preventDefault()`.

An `abort` event is fired at a transaction that has aborted. A `complete` event is fired a transaction that has successfully committed.

A transaction can fail for reasons unrelated to a particular request (e.g. quota exceeded, I/O error, etc). So if you want to be aware that a transaction has failed, watch for `abort` events. Similarly, because your logic may prevent the default behavior of a request error aborting the transaction, seeing an `error` event on a transaction does not tell you whether the transaction will eventually succeed or not.

Comment: just to make sure I understood correctly:
Assuming I'm using promise's then and catch as parallels to a transaction's success/failure:
onSuccess is the parallel of then and onAbort is the parallel of catch, correct?
(where as onerror refers to the request, so it is not part of the exact same cycle)

Comment: Not quite.

For a request, onsuccess is like then(), and onerror is like catch().

For a transaction, oncomplete is like then(), and onabort is like catch().